# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError with JDK 1.5

Tags: java, java-5

I am getting below exception with `Websphere 6.1` & `JDK 1.5` when trying to use `AdvancedGeoCoder` from `Google geocoding API` . Is JDK 1.5 is not supported by `google geocoding API`

```
[6/17/13 16:26:50:529 IST] 00000023 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[spring]: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (com/google/code/geocoder/AdvancedGeoCoder) bad major version at offset=6
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:258)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:555)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:597)
at com.americanexpress.imrcmr.controller.TwitterController.twitterSearch(TwitterController.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1102)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:570)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3444)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1466)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:119)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the MANIFEST from [geocoder-java-0.15.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/geocoder-java/geocoder-java/0.15/geocoder-java-0.15.jar), there is "Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_43". You can try to compile the lib yourself using a JDK 1.5.

Comment: I tried to compile but getting error message in Websphere  " The selected runtime does not support the version of the archive." . I checked version  geocoder-java-0.09.jar also . it is compiled in JDK 1.6 only . Is there any way to get JDK 1.5 compatible jar ?

Comment: I don't known the meaning of " The selected runtime does not support the version of the archive." error. The only posts I have googled are related to EAR. Have you dropped your self-built jar into "/WEB-INF/lib" folder of your web application ?

Comment: Yes . even I tried with new Application also. found workaround solution for now . Used HttpURLConnection to connect and consume Google API . thanks fro looking into this issue . Once we found solution , will update here ...

Answer (score 0):

That error usually appears when you are using diferent JDK version in your development environment and your server.

It seems you are compiling your app with JDK 6, but you are using JDK 1.5 in your server.

Answer (score 0):

you can compile like this
javac Filename.java -source  1.5  -target 1.5